# Find all iFrames in HTML page and replace them

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm wanting to use jQuery to find all iFrames in a page, then replace it's source.

I'm doing this from a chrome extension, so any way to replace it, then load the iframe (So that the iframe is active on the page view), is what I'm looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see you are a new user. If my answer solved your problem, please remember to mark the answer that solved your question. Thanks !

Comment: can you give us some more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can all instances of an element by calling a jquery selector on the element name:

```
$('iframe')
```

And you can set the attribute of any element with the jquery attr() method. To replace all the iframes on a page with google.com you would do this:

```
$('iframe').attr('src','http://google.com');
```

**--Disclaimer: The following code is an example of something referenced in the comments and is not an anwser to the Original question:**

This is how you would iterate each iframe and check it's width:

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
    var currentIframeWidth = $(this).width();
    //do something with width here
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to find specific iFrames with specific width and height?

Comment: I think its possible, but I would recommend that you add id's or classes to your iframes that are more easily selected.

Comment: I thought about it and you would have to call each() on the iframe selector and check each iframe for a specific width. However that is not what the question here is asking, so I didnt add that code example.

Comment: Feel free to add an example of it for me, lol. I'm having tons of issue with this ONE chunk of code.